# Merge Points data with GEOJSON in Hive

Tags: merge, hive, spatial

I have Points and shapefile converted to GEOJSON data uploaded in Hive. I'm doing visualization in Tableau with these files, but to do that I need to join both of the data.

The problem is the Points data don't have any common key if I want to do merging with the shapefile data.

I've done this with sample data in my desktop. The only think I know in order to merge the data, I need to assign the attribute of the shapefile to each of the points, and then do the merging based on the attributes.

I did it in QGIS, using Point Sampling Tools to do spatial joins, to get the attributes from the shapefile and then join the shapefile and the Points + attribute data in Tableau with common key (i.e. Region).

But since we are talking about big data here, around 19mio rows of data, I'm wondering if we can do the join in Hive?

Anyone that can help giving me ideas will be highly appreciated.
Many thanks!

Comment: Not really understanding your question, but you might take a look at the [GIS Tools for Hadoop (and Hive)](https://github.com/Esri/gis-tools-for-hadoop/).  [disclosure: collaborator]

Comment: I think your answer is more to take the Hadoop data and load into ArcGIS. Which ArcGIS is not an open source software so it's a little bit problem for me. I used QGIS now.

Comment: In the GIS Tools for Hadoop, only the Geoprocessing Tools for Hadoop require ArcGIS.  The Spatial Framework for Hadoop can be used independently of ArcGIS, and with only open source.  See also https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/167177/gis-tools-for-hadoop-for-qgis